# How do I authenticate terminus with machine token for Pantheon.io? I am getting a cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to set up terminus for `pantheon.io` and I am getting this error

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem

when I try to authenticate with a machine token. I am using `windows 10, wampserver, php 7`. I used composer and git bash to install terminus. I did download a `cacert.pem` file, put it in the `"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\extras\ssl"` folder, and I adjusted the `php.ini` file according to the documentation on github. I still get this error. What do I need to do to get it to work?

> [error]  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: did you add this to your curl request ?    curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   here $cSession is your variable for curl

Comment: Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: please share your curl request code

Answer (score 0):

I am using WampServer on windows 10 and WampServer has two php versions you can select from. Mine has 7.0.10 and 5.6.25. When I first tried to authenticate terminus with the machine token I had only modified the php.ini file for version 7.0.10. Well that didn't work so I modified the php.ini file for 5.6.25 and now it works. I don't know why but that fixed it for me.